# asp.net mvc converting list<> so to loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using this

```
  List<JobsMeta> JobsMeta= _db.JobsMetas.Where(m => m.int_OrganizationId == null || m.int_OrganizationId == OrganizationInfo.OrganizationId).OrderBy(m => m.int_SortId).ToList();
        ViewData["JobMeta"] = JobsMeta;
```

now using the view i want to loop through ViewData["JobMeta"]

```
<% foreach (var JobsMeta in ViewData["JobMeta"]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewData["JobMeta"] return object which you have to convert to list or to IEnumerable

```
<% var data = ViewData["JobMeta"] as List<JobsMeta>;
   foreach (var JobsMeta in data)
   { %> 
    html
<% } %>
```